# Show static user-set message in the notification bar on the Ubuntu panel (xfce)

Tags: ubuntu, notifications, textbox, panel, xfce

I'm running on Xubuntu 18.04.

Is there a way to add a specific text box to the notification taskbar on the top of the screen? i.e.

[image]

but I don't need the dropdown menu or any of that fancy stuff. All I want is a single text box that I can define a string for and will come up at boot forever and ever.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [xfce4-genmon-plugin](https://git.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-genmon-plugin/). You may disable its label and use `echo "your message"` as the command, or set the label to "your message" and `echo ""` as the command.

If you need something genmon-plugin can't provide, get [xfce4-sample-plugin](https://git.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-sample-plugin/) and tweak it to your liking.